# Ubuntu (Studio) suddenly not detecting monitors

Tags: display, monitor

Last night, all is well. This morning, only one of two monitors is detected, and only at a low resolution.  [Edit:  Ubuntu 20.04.]

I'm not an advanced user, but know enough to do these things:

```
lshw -c video

*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:54000000-54ffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff memory:52000000-53ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff


xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

Per one message I saw, I installed edid-decode.  That didn't change anything (though I merely installed it -- if there is config etc required, I wouldn't know what to do.)

I haven't installed or upgraded anything (unless it happened automagically) in the meantime -- literally 10 hours ago it was working fine.

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case this helps somebody else, I was able to solve the problem.

First I went ahead and upgraded everything ("sudo apt update" then "sudo apt upgrade"), and rebooted, though this action did not fix the problem (and might not have been relevant to the solution -- I did notice that NVidia drivers were upgraded at that time, but it didn't help.)

Second, I said "sudo ubuntu-drivers devices" (which showed some info), then "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall", then reboot.  And presto!  It's as if the problem never occurred.

I still have no idea what brought the problem on in the first, place, but everything seems to be back to normal.